# Git tab complete showing all Git command history

Tags: git, completion, git-completion

My tab complete for the `git` command shows the history of all git commands I've run.

I'm stumped on this one, and haven't found anything online that's helped me resolve this. Maybe I'm just using the wrong terms for the issue.

I was switching windows and running commands so fast keystrokes were happening in the wrong window, I get carried away. I think the cat even jumped up at one point while I was in the middle of running some commands.

Example `git push o` [tab]

```
....
 4014  git checkout origin/master
 4015  git branch -d master
 4016  git diff master
 4017  git branch -D master
 4018  git branch master
 4019  git checkout master
 4020  git log
 4021  git push origin master
 4026  git status
 4034  git status
 4035  git log
```

All other commands commands have I've tested are tab-completing normally. I even gave the whole system a restart.

- MacOS 10.15.7
- Git 2.29.2
- Git Completion 1.3

I would like to understand *why* this is happening and *how* to enable/disable whatever this is. Ideally, without just reinstalling or wiping configurations completely.

Comment: Have you tried updating both git and git completion?

Comment: This is likely due to a bug in the completion code. The git completion code is maintained by someone outside the Git project but updates go through the Git mailing list. If you're using zsh, note that the completion code was written for bash and some of the recent changes were to make it work better on zsh.

Comment: Update: A recent MacOS update included updates that resolved this issue.